# How to move all zero elements to the center of the array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Yesterday, I was struggling with a question asked by a company in their pre-screen round. The problem is that you will be given an array of integers. Your task is to move all the elements that have the value of zero into the middle of the array. To make it easier, center = floor(array.length/2).

I already had a solution, but it only works if you have only one zero element in your array.

I hope to receive better answers from you all.

Thank you.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {*} arr: a list of integers
 * @return: updated list of integers with all zero element moved to the middle
 * @example: [4,0,1,1,3] => [4,1,0,1,3]
 */
const zeroesToMid = (arr) => {
    const mid = Math.floor(arr.length/2)
    let result
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i] === 0) {
            let firstHalf = arr.splice(0,i)
            let secondHalf = arr.splice(i, arr.length)
            result = firstHalf.concat(secondHalf)
            result.splice(mid,0,0)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Asking for help isn't fair with people competing with you.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I was not able to solve this problem and ended up being rejected. That's why I'm here to look for help and learn from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments about your attempt:

- In each iteration you restart with a `result` based on `arr`. So actually you lose the result from every previous iteration.
- `splice` will move several array items: so this is not very efficient, yet you call it several times in each iteration. Moreover, you have at least one conceptual error here:

  ```
  let firstHalf = arr.splice(0,i)
  let secondHalf = arr.splice(i, arr.length)
  ```

  The first `splice` will actually *remove* those entries from `arr` (making the array shorter), and so the second call to `splice` will not have the desired result. Maybe you confused `splice` with `slice` here (but not later in your code).
- If the previous two errors were corrected, then there still is this: after a zero has been moved from index `i` to a *forward* position, there is now another value at `arr[i]`. But as the next iteration of the loop will have incremented `i`, you will never look at that value, which might have been zero too.
- `concat` creates a new array and you call it in each iteration, making it even more inefficient.

### Solution

Better than splicing and concatenating is to copy values without affecting the array size.

If it is necessary that the non-zero values keep their original order, then I would propose the following algorithm:

In a first iteration you could just *count* the number of zeros. From this you can derive at which *range* they should be grouped in the result.

In a second iteration you would copy a certain number op non-zero values to the left side of the array. Similarly you would do that at the right side as will. Finally, just *fill* the center section with zeroes.

So here is an implementation:

```js
function moveZeroes(arr) {
    // count zeroes
    let numZeroes = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) numZeroes += !arr[i];
    // Determine target range for those zeroes:
    let first = (arr.length - numZeroes) >> 1;
    let last = first + numZeroes - 1;
    // Move some non-zero values to the left of the array
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < first; i++, j++) {
        while (!arr[j]) j++; // Find next non-zero value
        arr[i] = arr[j];     // Move it to right
    }
    // Move other non-zero values to the right of the array
    for (let i = arr.length - 1, j = i; i > last; i--, j--) {        
        while (!arr[j]) j--; // Find next non-zero value
        arr[i] = arr[j];     // Move it to right
    }
    // Fill the middle section with zeroes:
    for (let i = first; i <= last; i++) arr[i] = 0;
    return arr;
}

// Demo
console.log(moveZeroes([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0]));
```

NB: If it is *not* necessary that the non-zero values keep their original order, then you could reduce the number of assignments even more, as you then only need to move the non-zero values that occur in the region where the zeroes should come. The other non-zero values can just stay where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach:
Problem statement doesn't specify, whether all zeros should be centered exactly (that requires counting zeros first), so we can just squeeze left and right parts, shifting non-zero elements to the corresponding end.

For example, left half might be treated like this sketch

```
cz = 0;
for(let i = 0; i <= mid;i++) {
    if (A[i])
        A[i-cz] = A[i];
    else
        cz++;
}
for(let i = mid - cz + 1; i <= mid;i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
}
```

Now increment `mid` if `cz>0` (so we have already filled central position with zero) and do the same for the right half in reverse direction (backward for-loop,  `A[i+cz] = A[i]`).

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, trincot does a spot-on analysis of what's wrong with your code.

I have what I think is a simpler solution to the problem though.  We can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the non-zero entries and then split that in half, then creating an output array by combining the first half with an appropriate number of zeros and then the second half.  It might look like this:

```js
const moveZeroes = (
  ns, 
  nonZeroes = ns .filter (n => n !== 0), 
  len = nonZeroes .length >> 1
) => [
  ... nonZeroes .slice (0, len), 
  ... Array (ns .length - nonZeroes .length) .fill (0),
  ... nonZeroes .slice (len)
]

const xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0]

console .log (... moveZeroes (xs))
console .log (... xs)
```

First off, `nonZeroes .length >> 1` takes advantage of bit-manipulation to create an expression that is simpler than `Math .floor (nonZeroes .length / 2)`.  It's like to be marginally faster too.  But they have equivalent behavior.

Notice in the output that the original array did not change.  This is very much intentional.  I simply much prefer working with immutable data.  But if you really want to change the original, we can just use `Object.assign`, to fold these new values back into the original array:

```js
const moveZeroes = (
  ns, 
  nonZeroes = ns .filter (n => n !== 0), 
  len = nonZeroes .length >> 1
) => Object .assign (ns, [
  ... nonZeroes .slice (0, len), 
  ... Array (ns .length - nonZeroes .length) .fill (0),
  ... nonZeroes .slice (len)
])

const xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0]

console .log (... moveZeroes (xs))
console .log (... xs)
```

Finally, I prefer the style demonstrated here of using only expressions and not statements.  But if you don't like the defaulted parameters for extra variables, this could easily be rewritten as follows:

```js
const moveZeroes = (ns) => {
  const nonZeroes = ns .filter (n => n !== 0)
  const len = nonZeroes .length >> 1
  return [
    ... nonZeroes .slice (0, len), 
    ... Array (ns .length - nonZeroes .length) .fill (0),
    ... nonZeroes .slice (len)
  ]
}
```

and again, we can use `Object .assign` if we want to.

The big trick here is that we're not actually moving the values, we're extracting some of them, and then simply sticking back together three separate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

here we have to take new array to return the value so it takes space complexity of O(n)

```
const fun = (arr)=>{
    new_array = []
    let zero_count = 0
    for(let i in arr)
      if(!arr[i])
        zero_count += 1
    
    let last_index = -1
    for(let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
     if (new_array.length >= Math.floor((arr.length - zero_count)/2)){
         last_index = i
         break;
     }
     if(arr[i]) new_array.push(arr[i]);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i<zero_count;i++)
        new_array.push(0)
    
    if (last_index != -1)
    for(let i =last_index;i<arr.length;i++)
        if(arr[i]) new_array.push(arr[i]);
        
    return new_array
}

console.log(fun([0,1,0,0,2,3,4,0,0]))
```

resultant output is [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,4]

**Time Complexity is O(n),
Space Complexity is O(n)**